# Using lapply in a nested loop

Tags: r, function, loops, nested-loops, lapply

I am trying to use the lapply() function on a list of random network objects to generate a list of corresponding communities for them (igraph package). I have done this outside of a loop and know that it works normally.

However, I am generating networks now in a nested loop and need to use lapply after my inner loop to generate this list of communities. I'm recording the average descriptive values of these two lists in the outer loop to make a dataframe of them.

Is it possible to use lapply() (or something with the same effect) within a nested loop, or should I just try and write a function with the same goal? I've included a code sample to show you what I mean, along with the error message I get when I run my code with the line `random_cs <- lapply(random_nws, cluster_optimal)`. I apologize if this is a little confusing.

```
random_nw_metrics <- data.frame( #to fill in
 
# Community 
  "count_communities" = NA,
  "ave_membership" = NA,
  "sd_membership" = NA,
  "modularity" = NA,

# General Network 
  # "assortativity" = NA, 
  "ave_distance" = NA,
  "degree_ave" = NA,
  "degree_sd" = NA,
  "density" = NA,
  "diameter" = NA,
  "reciprocity" = NA,
  "transitivity" = NA
) 


for (i in 1:180){ # it was "i in 1:nrow(df)", but that's not useful to you
  
set.seed(1)
random_nws <- list()
for (j in seq_len(1000L)) {
  
    Start = sample(15, 200, replace=TRUE)  # "15" and "20" change based on values from the df
    End   = sample(15, 200, replace=TRUE)
    df = data.frame(Start, End)
    
    ass.label <- data.frame("node" = 1:15, "type" = 0) # for assortativity labels
    ass.label$type <- +(match(ass.label$node, sample(x = 15, size = 5) ) > 0)
    ass.label[c("node", "type")][is.na(ass.label[c("node", "type")])] <- 0
    
    random_nws[[j]]<- graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = ass.label, directed=TRUE)
}


random_cs <- lapply(random_nws, cluster_optimal) #THIS IS THE THE LINE
nw <- random_nws[[i]]

random_nw_metrics <- rbind(random_nw_metrics, data.frame(
    
# Community 
  "count_communities" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) mean(length(x)))),
  "ave_membership" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) mean(membership(x)))),
  "sd_membership" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) sd(membership(x)))),
  "modularity" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) mean(modularity(x)))),

# General Network 
  # "assortativity" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(assortativity(x, V(x)$Type, directed = T)))), # this isn't working ignore it for now
  "ave_distance" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(mean_distance(x)))),
  "degree_ave" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(degree(x)))),
  "degree_sd" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) sd(degree(x)))),
  "density" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(edge_density(x)))),
  "diameter" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(diameter(x)))),
  "reciprocity" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(reciprocity(x)))),
  "transitivity" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(transitivity(x))))
)) 

}
```

Error:

```
no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
1.
lapply(random_nws, cluster_optimal)
```

Comment: Very likely the problem is coming from the `cluster_optimal` function used with the `lapply`.

Comment: You should look in to the help pages of this website on how to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Suren I did. The code is standalone if you have the igraph package.